# c#: try/catch DB exceptions does not work as expected

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, exception

I have following c# code that should help me handle DB exceptions:

```
  try
  {
      db.Demandeur_Categorie.Remove(vModifSupp);
      db.SaveChanges();
  }
  catch (SqlException ex)
  {
      msg = "Une erreur SQL s'est produite! La suppression dans la table 
      'Catégorie Demandeur' a échouée. Raison: " + ex;

      return Json(msg, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

But it throws an error

> ("The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   ...blabla) at the line    db.SaveChanges();

instead of going to the catch block.

Can someone help?

Comment: It's either what @Igor said, or if you're debugging, VS might be treating it as a first-chance exception (meaning it'll break on that like but will eventually go into the catch method)

Comment: If it is not problem for you. You can use catch without any parameter.

Comment: Replace your `SqlException` with `Exception`

Comment: S'il vous plaît, vous devez lire https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kcwalina/2005/03/16/design-guidelines-update-exception-throwing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code.

```
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     string typeString = ex.GetType().FullName;
     throw;
 }
```

And you'll see its probably not an SqlException

Answer (score 6):

The exception being thrown is not of type `SqlException`. Inspect the type at run time if you want to know the exact type. I also recommend you read up on how Exceptions work and type hierarchies.

Change it to `catch(DbUpdateException ex)`

See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechanges(v=vs.113).aspx), section **Exceptions**.

Comment: Checking the documentation for the exceptions thrown is always a good idea :)

Comment: Thanks, just ignorance from me.

Comment: @Patrice - I am glad to help. Please consider marking this as the answer using the check-mark on the left side of the answer.